# My selenium in Python is popping up with a bunch of errors, and the send keys and find element is not working

Tags: python, selenium

I am using Python. I got the lastest chrome download and the lastest selenium download, and I installed chromedriver.exe properly. Please help!

This is my code:
`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import random
import string
import time
PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://mail.protonmail.com/create/new?language=en')
usrnm = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(32)])
passwd = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for n in range(32)])
time.sleep(5)
emailad = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
emailad.send_keys(usrnm)

time.sleep(5)



driver.quit
```

`

This is the error code I am getting:
`

```
PS C:\Users\nuunu\OneDrive\Documents\pyscripts> & C:/Users/nuunu/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/nuunu/OneDrive/Documents/pyscripts/tester.py
c:\Users\nuunu\OneDrive\Documents\pyscripts\tester.py:12: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62286/devtools/browser/f06dc289-e1ab-482e-b8bb-9d838cc235a3

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:62296/devtools/browser/53203e50-b842-4cbe-95b6-9410751b9463
[17180:13148:1226/111315.478:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [11:13:15.478] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\nuunu\OneDrive\Documents\pyscripts\tester.py", line 19, in <module>
    emailad.send_keys(usrnm)
  File "C:\Users\nuunu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 233, in send_keys
    self._execute(
  File "C:\Users\nuunu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 410, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\nuunu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 444, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\nuunu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 249, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=108.0.5359.125)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x00EEF243]
        (No symbol) [0x00E77FD1]
        (No symbol) [0x00D6CF10]
        (No symbol) [0x00D9795E]
        (No symbol) [0x00D970E5]
        (No symbol) [0x00DB858C]
        (No symbol) [0x00D92BFF]
        (No symbol) [0x00DB8804]
        (No symbol) [0x00DCC9EB]
        (No symbol) [0x00DB8386]
        (No symbol) [0x00D9163C]
        (No symbol) [0x00D9269D]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x01189A22+2655074]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x0117CA24+2601828]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F98C0A+619850]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00F97830+614768]
        (No symbol) [0x00E805FC]
        (No symbol) [0x00E85968]
        (No symbol) [0x00E85A55]
        (No symbol) [0x00E9051B]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x774700F9+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77997BBE+286]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77997B8E+238]
```

`

For educational purposes, I was trying to make a bot to make an account for proton email, but it kept coming up with errors and I deleted a lot of code, and everything is working up untill the "emailad = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email')
emailad.send_keys(usrnm)"T

Comment: When you visit that url in a normal browser session, does the `email` input field appear as expected?

Comment: John Gordon, yes the email input field is shown when i visit that url and when i run the python script. I can inspect element even when running the python script and I will find the id of the email field, and its the same one as I used.